# PHP SIMPLEXML XPATH match multiple tags with same substring

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am doing a simple script that takes an XML as input, modifies some values, and saves it with another name.

The XML has multiple namespaces, often nested.

I am trying to find a clever solution to the following problem.

I have multiple tags which have a common substring, for instance Episode

```
<ext:EpisodeLong>Test</ext:EpisodeLong>
<ext:EpisodeBrief>Test</ext:EpisodeBrief>
<ext:EpisodeName>Test</ext:EpisodeName>
```

I want to access each and every tag that matches "Episode" and modify the value.

Relevant snipped of XML:

```
<Title endDateTime="2015-05-21T04:06:48Z" providerVersionNum="1" startDateTime="2015-05-02T04:06:48Z" uriId="c5.channel5.com/TITL0000000000001360">
    <core:Ext xmlns:core="http://www.cablelabs.com/namespaces/metadata/xsd/core/1">
        <ext:LocalizableTitleExt xmlns:ext="URN:NNDS:CMS:ADI3:01"    
        <xml:lang="eng">
            <ext:EpisodeLong>Test</ext:EpisodeLong>
            <ext:EpisodeBrief>Test</ext:EpisodeBrief>
            <ext:EpisodeName>Test</ext:EpisodeName>
        </ext:LocalizableTitleExt>
```

All xpaths I'm trying to do fail. If I do the line below, I fetch 99% of the XML, while I want everything under Title only.

```
$results = $xml->xpath('//*[contains(E:LocalizableTitleExt, Episode)]');
foreach ($results as $s) 
{
    echo "DEBUG, xpath has found: ".$s."<br/>";
    $elementsToRemove[] = $s;       
}
```

*assume all namespaces are registered already, E is ext, C is Core

Ideas?

Thanks in advance

ps: cannot use DOM, only SimpleXML and XPATH

Answer (score 0):

You can use `local-name()` function to get XML tag name. Also note that literal string need to be delimited using single or double quotes :

```
$results = $xml->xpath('//*[contains(local-name(), "Episode")]');
```

To contrast with the correct xpath above, the following xpath you tried... :

```
//*[contains(E:LocalizableTitleExt, Episode)]
```

... looks for an element having child element `<E:LocalizableTitleExt>` value containing value of another child element `<Episode>`.